# How to extract text between two characters in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to extract product information from between "en_US@" and ";" so for example if I was given "en_US@Terminal Block;" I would want Terminal Block returned. My method for doing this was:

```
=MID(B2, FIND("en_US@",B2)+6, FIND(";", B2, FIND("@", B2)+1)-FIND("@",B2)-1)
```

which is correct.

My question is can I write code to include "??_??@" as an option for the code to look for so I would look for either "en_US" or "??_??" to start the text extraction?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Could you please clarify what you mean by "code"? Are you referring to the formula, VBA, C+, what? It would also be nice to know what you have already tried and what the results were.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be working:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT( -- ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"en_US@","~?~?_~?~?@"},A1)))>0,MID(A1, FIND("@",A1)+1, FIND(";", A1, FIND("@", A1)+1)-FIND("@",A1)-1),"NA")
```

The magic is in the SUMPRODUCT( -- ISNUMBER(SEARCH({...},cell)))>0 bit, discussed [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things)

To specifically SEARCH() for a "?", you have to delimit each one with a tilde since search treats "?" as a wildcard by default.

The only other thing changed from your original is starting out with an IF() to see if it finds one of the character sequences, then finds the "@".